# Magento 2.2.2 issue mini cart not working

Tags: magento2.2, mini-cart

Centos 7 (se linux disabled)
nginx php 7.0.27
Luma theme
Magento 2.2.2

A very strange issue. Minicart not working I found a lot of posts but no one corrects my issue.
try setup:di / deploy static content fr_FR us_US

I see the mini cart updated when I add product. But when I click on this just blue button no text and button doesn't work.
In chrome developer mode I have this error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return getCartParam('summary_count') }"
Message: Unable to process binding "if: function (){return getCartParam('possible_onepage_checkout') }"
Message: Unable to process binding "click: function (){return closeMinicart() }"
Message: closeMinicart is not defined
    at click (eval at createBindingsStringEvaluator (knockout.js:2624), <anonymous>:4:87)
    at newValueAccessor (knockout.js:3839)
    at init (knockout.js:3849)
    at init (knockout.js:3842)
    at knockout.js:2989
    at Object.ignore (knockout.js:1249)
    at knockout.js:2988
    at Object.arrayForEach (knockout.js:151)
    at applyBindingsToNodeInternal (knockout.js:2974)
    at applyBindingsToNodeAndDescendantsInternal (knockout.js:2854)
```

I tried a test to switch interfaces to English US and it's working fine... No particular plugin.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 0):

are you using a custom theme and if so do you have a magento_checkout folder in there?

touching the minicart in magento is risky as it breaks quite easy. if you have not overwritten the checkout in your theme, replace the files in vendor/magento/module-checkout with the ones from the original installation.

If you have it in your theme folder too then you should undo any changes you have made.

make sure you check the logs and reports in var/log and var/report too to see if they can give you any extra infromation.